# About less than and negative values?

Tags: java

I just have a small beginners question, and it's about the code below. I want to check if the amount that the customer deduct from a credit account + the current balance don't getting lower than -5000 ? It's not working, and I'm wondering what I have done wrong? Is it about negative values? Help preciated!

```
// deduct credit account
if(type == "credit") {
    if((amountOut + creditAccountList.get(index).getAccountBalance()) < -5000) {
       System.out.println("Sorry! No deduct");
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The amountOut is a positive number that the customer enters. I still don't get it to work!? Could it be done in some other way? It seems so simple, byt yet so comlicated for me right now! I just want to prevent the customer to deduct a value if the balance is -5000? The problem is that the balance is a negative number.

Comment: What does "not working" look like?

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"? Do you ge a compiler error? A runtime error? A wrong result? What type does getAccountBalance() return? It's impossible to help you without more information.

Comment: Is amountOut +ve or -ve? It needs to be -ve for your code to work.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that info! Well, it seems like it don't dedect it and don't print the message. But I'm checking my code right now. Perhaps I have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to rewrite the condition. If I understood your case is the customer can withdraw an 5000 more than that of diposited amount. Example If customer has balance of 2000rs he/she can withdraw maximum 7000 rupees. If he/she wants to withdraw morw then your application will show "Sorry! No deduct" message. If this is the case then you can re-write the logic as given below

```
int thresholdMoney = 5000;
        if(((creditAccountList.get(index).getAccountBalance()+ thresholdMoney) - Math.abs(amountOut)) < 0){
            System.out.println("Sorry! No deduct");

        }
```

Comment: The case is that the customer have a credit of 5000, let's say, rupees, so my idea was to allow the customer to deduct/remove different values until the account balance reach -5000 rupees. If the customer deposit/insert money so that the balance is positive, then the customer doesn't use the credit.

Comment: Did you try with the logic that i have posted?

Comment: Yes, now I have and it worked nice! Thanks! The code was just a little bit confusing, but I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
if(type == "credit") {
```

with

```
if ("credit".equals(type)) {
```

Apart from that, the code seems to be correct, in order to double-check, I would run it through a debugger, or put the following error messages for quick and easy debug:

```
System.out.printf("out %d balance %d\n", amountOut, creditAccountList.get(index).getAccountBalance());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to subtract amountOut although its unclear what value you store in there.

```
if((creditAccountList.get(index).getAccountBalance() - amountOut) < -5000)
                                                     ^
                                              Changed from plus
```

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers work the same as they always have; it's more likely your logic that's off.

```
if((amountOut + creditAccountList.get(index).getAccountBalance()) < -5000){
```

If `amountOut` is positive, you'll never decrease the account balance.  Either make it negative or subtract it from the current balance to get the balance after withdrawal.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
// deduct credit account
if(type == "credit") {
    if((amountOut + creditAccountList.get(index).getAccountBalance()) > -5000){
   System.out.println("Sorry! No deduct");
}
}
```